# Create multiple copies of files in folder hierarchy from dropdown list

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a [master Excel sheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t1e74hhrrgbm98b/Distribution%20Macro%20Testing%20Upload.xlsm?dl=0) designed to spit out payroll details. The numbers on the sheet are driven by a data validation dropdown in A2, which fills in B2:G2 with identifying information (Last, First, Region, PayPeriod, Year) pulled from a data tab.

What I'd like to do is have a macro save a copy of the sheet for each choice in the dropdown into a specific folder in a hierarchy based on the info in B2:G2.

For instance,

```
ID    Last    First    Region    PP    Year
10001 Smith   Scott    DC        PP1   2016
```

I'd like that to save a sheet named "2016_PP1_DC_Smith_Scott.xlsx" in the folder C:\2016\PP1\DC.

And then change to

```
ID    Last    First    Region    PP    Year
10002 Jones   Karen    NY        PP3   2015
```

And save the sheet "2015_PP3_NY_Jones_Karen.xlsx" in the folder C:\2015\PP3\NY.

I have a macro that's part of the way there. It goes through each drop down and saves the file with the correct filename (Though it's renaming the initial file) (edit) I need help adding the functionality to save the sheets in a hierarchy of folders and not overwrite the original document with the most recent saved sheet name.

Totally fine with continuing to use this macro with edits or start from scratch.

```
Sub PrintValidationChoices()

    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim r As Long, i As Long
    Dim relativePath As String
    Dim year As String
    Dim quarter As String
    Dim pp As String
    Dim region As String
    Dim doctor As String

    Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook

    r = Range("ID").Cells.Count

        For i = 1 To r
        Range("A2") = Range("ID").Cells(i)

        year = ActiveSheet.Range("G2")
        pp = ActiveSheet.Range("F2")
        region = ActiveSheet.Range("E2")
        hospital = ActiveSheet.Range("D2")
        doctor = ActiveSheet.Range("B2") & "_" & ActiveSheet.Range("C2")

         'visually validating what will be used - not needed
        Range("H3") = year
        Range("H4") = pp
        Range("H5") = region
        Range("H6") = hospital
        Range("H7") = doctor

        sname = year & "_" & pp & "_" & region & "_" & hospital & "_" & doctor & ".xls"
        relativePath = wbSource.Path & "\" & sname 'use path of wbSource

        Range("H8") = relativePath

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=relativePath, FileFormat:=xlExcel8
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")) 'pausing to see actions - not needed

        Next i

        Range("A2") = Range("ID").Cells("1") 'return to start of list

    MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

Thank you guys for the help! If you're feeling verbose, it would be great to have some details in your response so I can learn.

Comment: So your macro gets you to a point, then you need help getting the final part? If that's it, what part do you need help with?  Or is the code you have giving you errors/unexpected results? Or is it not working at all, etc? I can't really tell what your question/issue is.

Comment: Hi Bruce - Thanks for the reply. My code will save a series of correctly named sheets in a single directory. I need help adding the functionality to save the sheets in a hierarchy of folders and not overwrite the original document with the most recent saved sheet name. I edited my original post to reflect that.

Comment: so you just want to get rid of the connection to `wbSource` path. Moreover shouldn't your 2nd example be _"And save the sheet "2015_PP3_NY_Jones_Karen.xlsx" in the folder C:\2015\PP3\NY."_ instead of _"And save the sheet "2016_PP1_NY_Jones_Karen.xlsx" in the folder C:\2015\PP3\NY."_?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "get rid of the connection"

Yes, updated that filename.

Comment: I mean that since you want folders path like "C:\2015\PP3\NY" which are mostly build up from cells contents except form the "C:\" part one, I guess that `relativePath = wbSource.Path & ...` is no longer needed

Comment: it seems to me a column's missing in your example: where is the "hospital" field?

Comment: @3598756 - Yes, there were a few changes I made in the post for simplicity sake. Hospital is another field that I would include in the hierarchy & filename, and I would prefer to have the items saved beginning in the root directory of wherever the original file is located.

Comment: FYI you must type "@" followed by _complete_ user name to have it informed a comment has been issued for him: in my case "@user3598756" instead of "@3598756"

Comment: @user3598756 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**edited** to reflect most probable *validation* worksheet name

maybe you're after something like what follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim strng As String
    Dim cell As Range

    With Worksheets("Report") '<--| change "Report" to your actual worksheet name
        For Each cell In Range(.Range("a2").Validation.Formula1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants)
            .Range("a2") = cell.Value
            SaveWorksheet .Range("B2:G2")
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub


Sub SaveWorksheet(rng As Range)
    Dim sname As String, relativePath As String
    Dim folder As String

        folder = "C:\" & rng(1, 6) & "_" & rng(1, 5) & "_" & rng(1, 4)
        MkDir folder

        sname = rng(1, 6) & "_" & rng(1, 5) & "_" & rng(1, 4) & "_" & rng(1, 3) & "_" & rng(1, 2) & "_" & rng(1, 3) & ".xls"
        relativePath = folder & "\" & sname

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False
        rng.Parent.Copy
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs filename:=relativePath ', FileFormat:=xlExcel8
            .Close
        End With
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")) 'pausing to see actions - not needed
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks 35987856 - I'm getting an error when I try to run that macro - "Subscript out of range" I did include a link to the workbook in the original post if that's helpful. https://www.dropbox.com/s/t1e74hhrrgbm98b/Distribution%20Macro%20Testing%20Upload.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Don't get it. Which code line gets highlighted when the code errors out?

Comment: When I run that macro from excel, the VBA window pops up with that error. When I Step Into the macro, It highlights Ln 3 with a yellow arrow. F5 to continue gives me an error.

Comment: you must change `"ValidationSheet"` to your actual worksheet name, which seems to be `"Report"` (I edited my answer with this latter).